# PHP - Editing object clone affects original object

Tags: php, oop, object, clone

So I have an object, let's call it Example.

```
class Example {
    public function __construct ($id) {
        $this->Id = $id;
    }
}

$objectA = new Example(10);
```

It has an id (it pulls this from somewhere), the goal of the object is to overwrite a similar object with this object's properties (post to an external service). This is done by simply changing the ID of the object, and running an ->update() method. However, it must first change its ID (among other properties) to match the ids of object B.

So what I do is clone the current object, reassign the needed properties, and then pass that cloned object to the update method, so that the update method uses the $post values for the update.

```
public function createPost ($id) {
    $post = clone $this;
    $post->Id = $id;
    return $post;
}

$objectA->update($objectA->createPost(12));
$objectA->update($objectA->createPost(16));
$objectA->update($objectA->createPost(21));
```

The issue I'm having is this object A needs to be used for multiple different updates, and it uses the ID it is originally assigned as a pointer to what IDs it must later use for $post, and in this scenario, the value of $this->ID is getting reassigned to the $id that is passed in ->setParameters(), even though I'm trying to assign it to a clone of $this, rather than $this itself.

My impression is that $objectA = $objectB assigns ObjectB to the same pointer that points to ObjectA, but that "clone" was supposed to actually make a copy of that object, so that if properties of the clone are changed, the original object remains unaffected, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Is there a particular method I should instead be using to ensure that the original object's value aren't ever changed when a clone of it is?

Comment: I am not following your code example.  WHere is `createPost()` (which returned clone) even used?

Comment: It's hard to understand this without knowing what `update` and `setParameters` do.

Comment: My bad, I meant to rename setParameters() to CreatePost() while I was still writing my post.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a deep clone.  Take a look at this [link.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Answer (score 0):

The issue I ran into here was a shallow cloning issue it would appear.

Forget what I referenced above, the problem was more so this: -

```
class Example {

    public function __construct ($id) {
        $this->ObjId = (object)array("Id" => 5);
        $this->Id = $id;
    }

}

$example = new Example (5);
$clone = clone $example;
$clone->ObjId->Id = 10;
```

In this example, I was trying to change the ->Id of a standard php object that was stored within my main object (I had used json_encode to pull a whole structure of objects) that was called "Id". The result of the above was this: -

```
echo $example->ObjId->Id; //10
echo $example->Id; //5

echo $clone->ObjId->Id; //10
echo $clone->Id; //5
```

So I had to write this method as part of the Example class: -

```
public function __clone () {
    foreach ($this as $key => $val) {
        if (is_object($val) || (is_array($val))) {
            $this->{$key} = unserialize(serialize($val));
        }
    }
}
```

So now, the result was this: -

```
echo $example->ObjId->Id; //5
echo $example->Id; //5

echo $clone->ObjId->Id; //10
echo $clone->Id; //5
```

This is because when I cloned the main Example object, it was creating an new variable for it's properties, but if one of it's properties was an object or array, it was copying the address of that object or array for the new cloned object. The above method prevents that, and does a "deep" copy.